# Degree of a morphisms between algebraic varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I wonder why if I have a morphism $\varphi:X \to Y$ and I know that $\varphi^*:H^*(Y) \to H^*(X)$ sends $O(1)$ to 0, I can deduce that $\varphi$ is a constant map. Is it related with the calculus of the degree of $\varphi$?

Comment: This assertion doesn't even make sense because $\mathcal O(1)$ is not defined and even if it were  it would not live in $H^*(Y)$.

Answer (score 2):

Your assertion is false in any interpretation (as it stands it doesn't even make sense) , as witnessed by the inclusion $\mathbb A^1\hookrightarrow \mathbb P^1$ and the fact that $H^1(\mathbb A^1)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of Georges shows that the premise of the question is false as things are currently written.

I will assume that $X$ and $Y$ are supposed to be projective varieties, and $O(1)$ an ample line bundle on $Y$. In that situation one can see your claim in the following way.

If $\varphi$ is nonconstant, then there is a curve $C$ in $X$ such that $\varphi(C)$ is a curve in $Y$. Then the projection formula tells you that $(\varphi^* O(1)) \cdot C = O(1) \cdot \varphi(C)$.

But since $O(1)$ is ample, the right-hand side is strictly positive, so $\varphi^*O(1)$ cannot be zero in $H^*(X)$.

Comment: Sorry if I wrote things incompletely. You are right: X and Y are projective varieties and $O(1)$ is a line bundle on Y. I also forgot to write that each group in $H^*(X)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$. Now the question is: if I don't know whether $\varphi$ is constant or not, can I show that in fact it is a constant map by showing that $\varphi^*(O(1))=0$?

Comment: @emilia: yes, I understood what the question was, and that is what my answer is explaining. (The hypothesis that each cohomology group is $\mathbf Z$ is not necessary.)

Comment: thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: You are welcome.